# Sass @for-loop doesn't render elements properly

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create some  elements that have a width that computes to a value according to whatever `$i` happens to be in the for loop. Upon checking the page in the browser, only 2 of the section elements are rendered with a height.

Upon inspection, `:nth-child(2)` is being applied to the first section. `:nth-child(3)` is being applied to the second section. As for the last section, it has a length, but no height.

Why is `$i == 1` being skipped upon the first iteration of the for loop? What can be done to remedy this so each each loop applies the properties accordingly in the browser?

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1></h1>
    </header>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**SASS**

```
$color: red;

body {

  header {
    text-align: center;
    color: $color;
  }

  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    section:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      width: calc(100vw - 10vw * #{$i});
      height: 200px;
      border: 10px solid;
      margin: 10px auto;
      background: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
body header {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
body section:nth-child(1) {
  width: calc(100vw - 10vw * 1);
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: red;
}
body section:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100vw - 10vw * 2);
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: red;
}
body section:nth-child(3) {
  width: calc(100vw - 10vw * 3);
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<header>` is counted as first child, but the style is not applied to it because it is not a section.

If you want to iterate only through sections you can use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`.